# Slash command not being listed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So 2 out of 3 commands that i made show up on discord.com...

[image: command list]

But I can't get the 3rd one to show up.
All 3 command files have the exact same structure:

```
let { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('yt')
        .setDescription('link to ait youtube page'), 
        async execute(interaction) {
            await interaction.reply('(link)');
        },
};
```

```
let { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('pong'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply('Pong!');
    },
};
```

```
let { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('rules')
        .setDescription('server rules'),
        async execute(interaction) {
            await interaction.reply('(rules)');
        },
};
```

Here's my main.js:

```
// let {...}...
let fs = require('node:fs');
let path = require('node:path');

// let client...

client.commands = new Collection();

let cmdPath = path.join(__dirname, 'cmd');
let cmdFiles = fs.readdirSync(cmdPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (let file of cmdFiles) {
    let filePath = path.join(cmdPath, file);
    let command = require(filePath);

    if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
        client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    } else {
        console.log(`[warn] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
    }
}

// client.login(token)...

//client.on('ready', () => ...)...

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    let command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) {
        console.error(`[warn] No command matching '${interaction.commandName}' was found.`);
        return;
    }

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`[warn] Error occured running command '${interaction.commandName}'`);
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
```

This is probably an uncommon problem, but if you know how to fix it, let me know.‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌

Comment: It usually takes up to 2 hours for Slash commands to appear in your server. If nothing happens after 2 or more hours, double check your code for errors. Also, double check if the file actually is included, and not left out, e.g., typos in the (file)names

Comment: @node_modules Discord made an update, now they appear almost instantly